# TripleDES encryption - c# and javascript differences

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption

I have data encrypted in c#, and need to put together a demo of how to decrypt in javascript.  (Note, this is just for a demo - we will not be putting keys into client side code!)

I cannot get the settings right using Crypto-js - I've tried lots of variations, but am getting nowhere.

I cannot change the c# code, so need to get the javascript to work the same way.

Current skeleton code is as follows -

C# (encrypt)

```
    var EncryptionKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("14ggh11dd3fvv4n4aabb33a3");
    var IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("312a44de");

    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    tdes.Key = EncryptionKey;
    tdes.IV = IV;

    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test");

    var ciphertext = Convert.ToBase64String(tdes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ciphertext));
```

which generates the cipher VrB1Ih0Ll%2fQ%3d

javascript (decrypt)

```
function decryptByDESModeCBC(ciphertext) {
    var key = '14ggh11dd3fvv4n4aabb33a3';
    var iv = '312a44de'

    ciphertext = decodeURIComponent(ciphertext);
    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    var ivBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv);

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext)
    }, keyBytes, {
        iv:ivBytes,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    });
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}


function test()
{
  console.log(decryptByDESModeCBC("VrB1Ih0Ll%2fQ%3d"));
}
```

Expected result is "test", but I am getting blank.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Did you call `test()`?

Comment: yes - I am running the code.

Comment: Just use `CryptoJS.TripleDES` instead of `CryptoJS.DES`.

Comment: Perfect - I can't tell you how many hours I've spent on this!   If you want to put it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @Topaco in the comments

I needed to use `CryptoJS.TripleDES` instead of `CryptoJS.DES`